# FATAL EXCEPTION: main InputStreamReader

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      DownloadJSONTask task = new DownloadJSONTask();
      task.execute("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=36b8f53d62feede472b8646af200cc8b");
}
private static class DownloadJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            URL url = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line = reader.readLine();

                while (line != null){
                    result.append(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
                return result.toString();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(urlConnection != null){
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return  null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Log.i("MyResult", s);
        }
    }
```

Приложение вылетает на строке:

```
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream)
```

> 2019-07-26 22:38:38.053 27153-27153/com.android.example.salar
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.android.example.salar, PID: 27153
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Answer (score 0):

А после `url.openConnection()` не нужно разве вызывать `urlConnection.connect()`?

Ну и вообще, после установки соединения хорошо бы статус ещё проверять:

```
url = new URL(strings[0]);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    // тут уже InputStream берём
}
```

Comment: Попробовал не помогло. Код переписан один в один с урока. должен работать так как есть. Но у меня не видит потока по ссылке, вылетает ошибка. В чем может быть причина не пойму.

Comment: Запустил код с другого приложения, там он работает. Сравнил manifest build.gredle все одинаково. единственное отличие это миграцыя на androidX.